# Semantic UI footer at the end

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic-UI in my project. I created an index page, everything works ok with the elements (navbar, footer, etc).

Now Im dev a signup page but footer does not goes to the end of the page, what can I do ?

**Footer code:**

```
<div class="ui inverted vertical footer segment">
    <div class="ui container">
        Travel Match 2015. All Rights Reserved
    </div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** I do not have any css rules(yet) in the footer, only the ones added by semantic-ui

**UPDATE:**
navbar code:

```
<div class="ui inverted segment">
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="ui inverted secondary menu">
            <div class="item">
                <i class="plane icon app-icon"></i>
            </div>
                <div class="right item">
                  <a href="/signup">Signup</a>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

form code:

```
    <form class="ui large form container">
        <div class="ui stacked segment">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="user icon"></i>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui left icon input">
                    <i class="lock icon"></i>
                    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui error message"></div>
    </form>
    <div class="striped"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your full code?

Comment: Many things could go wrong, without seeing the actual code it's very hard to predict. A reference to the code would be great.

Comment: what code do you need guys? footer and the form?

Comment: Post the demo of the current behavior.

Comment: @ManojKumar how can I do that?

Comment: Shows us the page you are working on or use this: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: @ManojKumar I cant add semantic-ui to the snippet

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try `absolute` positioning since your content is smaller than the section in [**Semantic-ui docs**](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/container.html).

Use `min-height` for applying the CSS rule as the footer is placed at the bottom at certain height range and thus avoiding any overlap over the content.

```css
@media (min-height: 320px) {
  .ui.footer.form-page { /* Increased specificity for SO snippet priority */
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ui inverted segment">
    <div class="ui container">
      <div class="ui inverted secondary menu">
        <div class="item">
          <i class="plane icon app-icon"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="right item">
          <a href="/signup">Signup</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form class="ui large form container">
    <div class="ui stacked segment">
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui left icon input">
          <i class="user icon"></i>
          <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail address">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <div class="ui left icon input">
          <i class="lock icon"></i>
          <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="ui fluid large teal submit button">Login</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui error message"></div>
  </form>
  <div class="striped"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui inverted vertical footer segment form-page">
  <div class="ui container">
    Travel Match 2015. All Rights Reserved
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works with the form page but it break the index page

Comment: Use a different class for the footer in form page.

Comment: what do you mean different class? im using templates to reuse code

Comment: Check my code edit. I have included a class for the footer in HTML and modified the CSS. Use it only on the form page and remove the `.form-page` from index.

Comment: For me work this:  `@media (min-width: 723px)`